# dplyr "promise already under evaluation" error when trying to do conditional type conversion

Tags: r

I am attempting to use `dplyr::mutate` to take a character variable and create a numeric variable from it. The method I'm using gives me an error and I'm not sure why.

Example: a data frame with two character variables. One always has strings that can convert to an integer, and one sometimes has the letter "E" instead. I would like to convert both columns to numbers, substituting the letter "E" with zero.

```
df <- data.frame(
    always_numstring=c("4", "1", "3"), 
    usually_numstring=c("4", "1", "E"))
```

The following line works as expected:

```
df %>% mutate(x=ifelse(always_numstring=="E", 0, as.numeric(always_numstring)))

  always_numstring usually_numstring x
1                4                 4 4
2                1                 1 1
3                3                 E 3
```

The following line does not:

```
df %>% mutate(x=ifelse(usually_numstring=="E", 0, as.numeric(usually_numstring)))

Error in base::nchar(wide_chars$test, type = "width") : 
  promise already under evaluation: recursive default argument reference or earlier problems?
```

I didn't even expect it to try to convert "E" to numeric. More importantly I don't understand why this is fatal when `as.numeric("E")` usually is not.

Here's a non-dplyr version that gives a warning but then works as intended:

```
df$x <- ifelse(df$usually_numstring=="E", 0, as.numeric(df$usually_numstring))
Warning message:
In ifelse(df$usually_numstring == "E", 0, as.numeric(df$usually_numstring)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

df
  always_numstring usually_numstring x
1                4                 4 4
2                1                 1 1
3                3                 E 0
```

Questions:

1. What's an appropriate way to do what I want using dplyr: check a string for illegal values and convert to a number only if appropriate?

Bonus questions:

2. It's apparently dying when it tries to convert "E" to numeric. Why is that fatal?
3. Why this particular error message?
4. Can you point to an explanation for why ifelse() is evaluating both the `yes` and the `no` expression? My default was to expect it to act like `if()` here.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento the first version uses `always_numstring` and the second uses `usually_numstring`. But @octern, I’m not getting that error message with your posted code — just the coercion warning.

Comment: @zephryl - oops, right you are. Indeed, I also don't encounter any error.  As an aside to OP, you should coerce to numeric on the result of your ifelse call, not inside it - that way you'll avoid the warning.

Comment: @zephryl That is helpful. I had a feeling that this might have started happening after some package updates, but I wasn't sure. I even tried downgrading dplyr (1.0.10 > 1.0.6) without effect. Unfortunately I updated a lot of packages and don't have any other guesses as to what might have caused it...

Comment: Do you have any other packages loaded? Do you get the same error in a fresh session with no packages loaded besides dplyr?

Comment: The problem is unreproducible in a new session, even with the same packages loaded, and the actual code I was working on is behaving as desired too. I suppose the error was just complicated-sounding enough for me to not realize it didn't make sense & I should try reloading. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @zephryl See response above. If you wish feel free to post the answer "this error is not standard behavior and you should try restarting your session," otherwise I'll do so in case anyone else ever gets themselves into the same broken state.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my session fixed this. If you are getting this error and don't understand why, try restarting before any deeper debugging.